# Condition not matching the expected behaviour

Tags: lua

I have two records which are being passed to below if else

> Record1 : START SUITE: Android [ ]

> Record2 : START SUITE: Android.Test the user dashboard [ ]

in the string match i am trying to differentiate these both one has **Android [ ]** while other is **Android.**

here is my conditions

```
if  record.message ~= nil and string.match(record.message, "START SUITE: Android[ ]") then
    new_record["name"] = "A"
    if string.match(record.message, "START SUITE: Android.") then
        getname(record.message)
        new_record["name"] = "B"
    end
end
```

Here the problem is the 1st record is coming to second condition even it don't have the **Android.** in the record and getting the name "B" instead of staying in 1st condition how can i resolve this?

**Note:** i have multiple records and getting them dynamically so that's why not adding directly `Android.Test the user dashboard` to the second condition to stop the entry of 1st.

Comment: I told you to escape magic characters in your last post ;-)

Comment: @Piglet, i tried below answer but no luck.

`record = "START SUITE: Android [ ]"
if  record ~= nil and string.match(record, "START SUITE: Android%[ %]") then
    print("A")
    if string.match(record, "START SUITE: Android%.") then
        print("B")
    end
end`

Answer (score 0):

`string.match` takes a [pattern](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1):

- `.` in a pattern matches any character;
- `[...]` in a pattern is a character class where `...` are a bunch of
  ranges or characters. `[ ]` matches exactly the space character  .

Anything that matches `"START SUITE: Android [ ]"` - equivalent to `"START SUITE: Android  "` as a pattern - will thus match `"START SUITE: Android."`, because the space character ( ) matches any character (`.`).

To avoid this, escape your patterns properly using the `%` sign:

- `"START SUITE: Android [ ]"` becomes `"START SUITE: Android %[ %]"`
- `"START SUITE: Android."` becomes `"START SUITE: Android%."`

As you just want to check whether the string contains a substring and don't care about the match, you might want to use [`string.find (s, pattern [, init [, plain]])`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#6.4.1) instead of `string.match`. This will return `nil` - which is falsy - if the substring is not found, or an index (and more which usually gets discarded) - which is truthy - if the substring is found. Additionally, you can pass the `plain` parameter to make sure `pattern` is interpreted as a `plain` substring rather than a pattern. Using this, you could rewrite your code as follows:

```lua
if record.message ~= nil and string.find(record.message, "START SUITE: Android [ ]", 1, true) then
    new_record["name"] = "A"
elseif string.find(record.message, "START SUITE: Android.", 1, true) then
    getname(record.message)
    new_record["name"] = "B"
end
```

you might want to write yourself a handy utility for this "contains" check equivalent to `not not string.find(s, pattern, 1, true)`.

The nested `if` becomes obsolete; if the first `if` matches, the second `if` can't possibly match unless the subject string contains both strings. I have thus moved it to an `elseif` branch.

Comment: `record = "START SUITE: Android [ ]"
if  record ~= nil and string.match(record, "START SUITE: Android%[ %]") then
    print("A")
    if string.match(record, "START SUITE: Android%.") then
        print("B")
    end
end`
I tried this it returns nothing

Comment: @Zain Ah sorry, I missed the space after `Android`. Should be fixed now.

Comment: Thanks let me test i will give update :)